# How to make a list of primitive values based on the list of objects - Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I got list of objects. Each object has its values.
`data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)` so I have a list of 15 Users each of them got name and age. How to make a separate list with only ages? Like convert listOfUsers to listOfAges?

Comment: `ages = users.map(User::age)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Transform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html) the collection using `map`:

```
val listOfAges = listOfUsers.map { it.age }
```